# CK Editor - assigning ID

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to get CKEditor to use an unique ID that I can use some jQuery to grab the value within a ajax request.
Can anyone suggest how I can set the ID for the editor?
Below is the code
http://pastebin.com/eTP7xnKr

Comment: Does anyone know if this code could be replicated in jQuery (rather than MooTools)
http://fragged.org/ckeditor-blues-when-it-fails-to-pass-on-the-data-via-ajax_1363.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, you can also set many other attributes:

$CKEditor->textareaAttributes = array("id" => $fieldname, "cols" => 40, "rows" => 4, 'style' => "width: {$width}; height: {$height}; position: relative; overflow: auto;");

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in ckeditor.php it will tell you how.

Sorry, I don't have a clever answer...

Comment: I did find this but it didnt work unfortunately
config.bodyId = 'YOUR_ID_HERE';